# Accessing DynamoDB over the browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

On a project, I am required to access Amazon's DynamoDB directly from the browser. There is aws-sdk-js for node.js, but not for the browser side JS, so I'm trying to access using Amazon's HTTP API. Are there any implementations for this?

Are there any implementations available for the signing process? (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to implement it myself, but the official aws-sdk-js now supports browser side JavaScript.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at a [series of posts](http://blog.engelke.com/2011/12/04/the-bookshelf-project-using-amazon-web-services-from-javascript/) on my blog. [Part 3](http://blog.engelke.com/2011/12/11/chrome-web-app-bookshelf-part-3/) has code that covers almost exactly what you want, though for a different AWS API. But it includes signing a request:

```
function computeSignature(params, secretAccessKey){
      var stringToSign = 'GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n' +
                         createQueryString(params);
      var key = sjcl.codec.utf8String.toBits(secretAccessKey);
      var hmac = new sjcl.misc.hmac(key, sjcl.hash.sha256);
      var signature = hmac.encrypt(stringToSign);
      signature = sjcl.codec.base64.fromBits(signature);

      return signature;
   }
```

That post includes the code for `createQueryString` used above. Cryptographic functionality is provided by the [Stanford JavaScript Cryptography Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) (the `sjcl` object above).

[All the code](https://github.com/engelke/bookshelf) in the blog series is also on Github, so you don't have to copy and paste things piece by piece from the blog.